# add vertical lines to plot at dates where column contains text

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, plotly

```
import plotly as plotly
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'height': [712, 712, 716, 716, 718, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                           'moisture': [0.06, 0.19, 0.18, 0.17, 0.18, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                           'tasks': ['water', None, None, 'prune', None, None, 'position', None, 'prune', None]}, 
                           index=['2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
                            '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13'])

df.index.name = 'date'
```

From the `df` I want to plot a 'line' graph and add vertical lines at all `index` `date` points where a value appears in `df.tasks` column irrespective whether there is a value in the corresponding `height` row or not.

I am able to plot the 'line' grapgh only with the basic line representing the height values but not the verticals, using .....

```
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.height)
```

After this I created dictionary from which I think the vertical lines from could be generated from....

```
index_tasks = df[~df.tasks.isnull()]


task_dict = index_tasks.groupby('date')['tasks'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

However, even after exploring the plotly documentation, I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you for reading and hopefully you can lend a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you really described what needs to be coded
- in **plotly** *shapes* of which a *vline* is a type of *shape* are part of the layout not the trace.  Hence simplest way is to add them after figure is created.

```
import plotly as plotly
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'height': [712, 712, 716, 716, 718, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                           'moisture': [0.06, 0.19, 0.18, 0.17, 0.18, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                           'tasks': ['water', None, None, 'prune', None, None, 'position', None, 'prune', None]}, 
                           index=['2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
                            '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13'])


fig = px.line(df, y="height")

for x in df.loc[~df["tasks"].isna()].index:
    fig.add_vline(x=x)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Good gosh you made that look simply! thanks. Can we add a legend to identify each vertical line?